# Django: URL path is not working / 404 Page not found

Tags: python, django, api

I'm trying to build an API with Django for the first time. To see if everything works, I tried to implement a get method at a "try/" endpoint and return a simple json containing "name":"myname".

The django app is running succesfully and the admin page works as intended. The endpoint "admin/try" is not reachable though and returns a 404.

I have all the files related to the api in a seperate folder, not in the folder of the actual app. This should, according to some tutorials, not be a problem.

This is the GET method I am trying to call at the "try/" endpoint. Its located in views.py in the api folder.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET'])
def tryMethod(request):
    something = {'name':'myname'}
    return Response(something)
```

This is the urls.py file in the api folder:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('try/', views.tryMethod)]
```

This is the urls.py file in the folder of the actual app

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from drf_spectacular.views import SpectacularAPIView, SpectacularSwaggerView
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
               path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
               path('health/', views.health, name='health'),
               path('schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='schema'),
               path('docs/', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='swagger-ui'),
               path('404', views.handler404, name='404'),
               path('500', views.handler500, name='500'),
               path('', include('api.urls')),
               ]
```

This is the error screen:
[Error 404, Page not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwPks.png)

Comment: **Typo**: you are making a request to `/admin/try` whereas your path is actually`/try/`

Comment: That is absolutely true. It works at http://localhost:3000/try. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screen, I conclude that you are requested `http://localhost:3000/admin/try`

To get response from this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def tryMethod(request):
    something = {'name':'myname'}
    return Response(something)
```

You need request `http://localhost:3000/try`